# Angular 2 firebase authenticating

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm using Angular 2 with Firebase. I'm using the Angular angularfire2 package to use firebase.

1. How I can get the user ID from the firebase `auth` variable once the user is logged in?
   I tried to `console.log(auth);` and couldn't find any assosication to `id`.
2. Is it possible to query the `Auth` user list? that seem like Firebase is not adding the users to the database, but to the `Auth` section in the console.
3. Is it possible to assign roles and additional user information to users in the `Auth` console? Or I have to creae `user` table and store this data myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question number 1 the auth state object has the `uid` property so try `console.log(auth.uid)` and you'll get it.

For questions 2 and 3 the short answer is no. But you can have a `users` entry in your Firebase database and any time a new user is created in your app, you can use the `uid` from the auth state to set a new user. Then roles and anything else you want is up to your imagination.